# How to make a line dashed or dotted in chartJS?

Tags: chart.js, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG and have a line chart set up that has two data sets. one of those lines is solid, and i'd like to make the other line dashed or dotted. is there an option for this in ChartJS?

Answer (score 11):

My bad, took another look at the [chartjs doc](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html)s and found it! You can set it with the `borderDash` option. Set mine to `borderDash: [10,10]`